# ¿Cómo hago para calcular la parte entera usando JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#n1").on("click", function(){
    $("#n1").val("");
  });

  $("#b1").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
    num.val(num.val() * num.val());
  })


  $("#b2").on("click", function() { 
    var num = $("#n1");
    num.val(1/num.val());
  })

  $("#b3").on("click", function(){
    var num = $("#n1");
    num.val(Math.sqrt(num.val()));
  })

  $("#b4").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
    if (num.val()>0){
      num.val() = Math.floor(num.val());
    }
    if (num.val()<0){
      num.val() = -Math.ceil(num.val());
    }
  })

  $("#b5").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
  })
});

acc = 0, op = "";

function mas() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "+"; 
}
function menos() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "-"; 
}
function multiplicacion() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "*"; 
}
function division() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "/"; 
}
function xelevadoy(){
  acc = num.value;
  op="xelevadoy"; 
}
function calcular() {
  if (op === "+") {
    num.value = (+acc + +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "-") {
    num.value = (+acc - +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "*") {
    num.value = (+acc * +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "/") {
    num.value = (+acc / +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "xelevadoy") {
    num.value = Math.pow(+acc,+num.value);
  }
}

function inic () {
  num = document.getElementById("n1"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Calculadora</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <h1>Bienvenido a la calculadora de Luis R.</h1>

  </head>
  <body onLoad="inic()">

    Número:
    <input type="text" id="n1" onclick="vaciar()"></input>
    <p>
      <button id="b1" onclick="cuadrado()">x<sup>2</sup></button>
      <button id="b2" onclick="inverso()"> 1/x </button> 
      <button id="b3" onclick="sqrt()"> sqrt(x) </button> 
      <button id="b4" onclick="parte_entera()"> parte_entera(x) </button> 
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="b5" onclick="mas()">+</button>
      <button id="b6" onclick="menos()">-</button>
      <button id="b7" onclick="multiplicacion()">*</button>
      <button id="b8" onclick="division()">/</button>
      <button id="b9" onclick="xelevadoy()">x<sup>y</sup></button>
      <button id="b10" onclick="calcular()">=</button>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tengo un problema en el bloque de código:

```
$("#b4").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
    if (num.val()>0){
        num.val() = Math.floor(num.val());
    }
    if (num.val()<0){
        num.val() = -Math.ceil(num.val());
    }
})
```

Necesito poder calcular la parte entera de un numero (ejemplo: Si ingreso `-3.6` este debería devolver `3`), ¿Cómo solucionar esto?

Comment: Noto algunas inconsistencias en tu código, te las enumero para ver si puedes mejorarlo:

--- la funcion `vaciar` no está definida

--- con estas sentencias `+acc,+num.value` no estás haciendo nada, ya que el operador `+` precediendo algo no hace nada, a diferencia del operador `-` que cambia el signo del numero.

--- Aquí incluso debería darte error `num.val() = -Math.ceil(num.val());` dado que estás asignando el resultado de una función (`ceil`) al resultado de otra función (`num.val()`), quizás debas cambiarlo a `num.value`

Answer (score 3):

Primero unas recomendaciones:

- limpia tu código. Parece que has movido lo que antes eran funciones y eventos `onclick` *inline* a controladores de evento con jQuery, pero has dejado todo el código *inline* que ahora es sólo "basura" y que hará que falle el código (con llamadas a funciones inexistentes).
- sé consistente. Sólo has movido la mitad de las funciones a controladores jQuery, dejando el resto como funciones independientes con sus `onclick` *inline* en las etiquetas. Es mejor que lo hagas todo de la misma manera; hará el mantenimiento y la depuración más sencillos.
- aprende a depurar. Es una de las habilidades más útiles para un programador, en JavaScript es superfácil (abriendo la consola de JS pulsando en F12 o Ctrl+Shift+J dependiendo del navegador) y te ayudará a resolver problemas en menos tiempo del que tardas en escribir una pregunta en StackOverflow (en serio).

---

Y ahora la solución. Sigue estos pasos:

> Nota: no voy mover las funciones que faltan a controladores de jQuery, pero sí voy a quitar los `onclick` inline de los elementos `#n1`, `#b1`, `#b2`, `#b3`, `#b4` y `#b5` porque ya las movieste y te generará problemas si no los quitas.

Una vez corregidos los `onclick`, sólo queda un error que está cuando haces `num.val() = [valor]`. `.val()` es una función a la que debes pasarle el nuevo valor como parámetro, no asignarle un valor. Por lo que debes hacer `num.val([valor])` en su lugar. Curiosamente, lo haces bien en las otras funciones, sólo lo pusiste mal en esa.

Haciendo esos cambios, ya funciona sin problemas:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#n1").on("click", function(){
    $("#n1").val("");
  });

  $("#b1").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
    num.val(num.val() * num.val());
  })


  $("#b2").on("click", function() { 
    var num = $("#n1");
    num.val(1/num.val());
  })

  $("#b3").on("click", function(){
    var num = $("#n1");
    num.val(Math.sqrt(num.val()));
  })

  $("#b4").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
    if (num.val()>0){
      num.val(Math.floor(num.val()));
    }
    if (num.val()<0){
      num.val(-Math.ceil(num.val()));
    }
  })

  $("#b5").on("click", function() {
    var num = $("#n1");
  })
});

acc = 0, op = "";

function mas() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "+"; 
}
function menos() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "-"; 
}
function multiplicacion() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "*"; 
}
function division() {
  acc = num.value; 
  op = "/"; 
}
function xelevadoy(){
  acc = num.value;
  op="xelevadoy"; 
}
function calcular() {
  if (op === "+") {
    num.value = (+acc + +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "-") {
    num.value = (+acc - +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "*") {
    num.value = (+acc * +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "/") {
    num.value = (+acc / +num.value);
  }
  if (op === "xelevadoy") {
    num.value = Math.pow(+acc,+num.value);
  }
}

function vaciar() {}

function inic () {
  num = document.getElementById("n1"); 
}

inic();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <h1>Bienvenido a la calculadora de Luis R.</h1>


    Número:
    <input type="text" id="n1"></input>
    <p>
      <button id="b1">x<sup>2</sup></button>
      <button id="b2"> 1/x </button> 
      <button id="b3"> sqrt(x) </button> 
      <button id="b4"> parte_entera(x) </button> 
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="b5" onclick="mas()">+</button>
      <button id="b6" onclick="menos()">-</button>
      <button id="b7" onclick="multiplicacion()">*</button>
      <button id="b8" onclick="division()">/</button>
      <button id="b9" onclick="xelevadoy()">x<sup>y</sup></button>
      <button id="b10" onclick="calcular()">=</button>
    </p>
```

Pero lo dicho, esto lo podías hacer solucionado en cuestión de un par de minutos desde la consola de JAvaScript. Realmente te recomiendo que aprendas a usarla.

Answer (score 2):

Buen días, para la función parte entera de un número, solo necesitas usar el siguiente código:

```js
var numero = 3.5;
var resultado = Math.floor(numero);
```

Aquí te dejo [información](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp) sobre la función mencionada. Ahora bien, floor te va a funcionar solo con número positivos, pero eso lo solucionas poniendo un if y multiplicando por -1 sí el número fuera menor a 0;

```js
var numero = -8.6;
if (numero < 0)
   numero *= -1;
var resultado = Math.floor (numero);
```